# How to find a chrome driver for my chrome version?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to install RSelenium for webscraping but am not able to get a chromedriver that matches with my current chrome version. I do not want to downgrade to an older google chrome as that seems to not be advised.

On updates as well, my chrome version seems to update to a version for which google chrome driver is not available. Currently, my chrome version is 119.0.6045.160 for which a chrome driver is not yet available. This seems to be a recurring issue where I seem to miss out on the chrome driver that could be compatible with my current chrome version on update. I am new to this and may be missing out on something, so please help me out! I want to add that I want to scrape on R, so any guidance on how to do this on R, would be very helpful.

Comment: In the context of **R**Selenium, ChromeDriver is generally managed by  `wdman`, which has not yet updated to support new driver distribution urls, there's an open issue - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/issues/34 - with workarounds. And an open(!) pull request that aims to target this - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/pull/39 . If you feel adventurous, you can install the PR from github: `remotes::install_github("ropensci/wdman#39")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Currently, my chrome version is 119.0.6045.160 for which a chrome driver is not yet available"***

Above is not true. Only the major versions MUST match for compatibility. So in your case versions `119` needs to match. Match of minor version(`0`), patch(`6045`) and build(`160`) is optional.

There is a stable version of ChromeDriver which is available for GoogleChrome `v119`. You can use it.

Visit the below link and download `chromedriver.exe` based on your system's platform(i.e. windows, Linux etc.)

[Link to download latest stable version of `chromedriver.exe`](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)