How to install and specify correct driver version for RSelenium for Chrome v115.0 and later?
Most of the instructions for setting up Chrome servers with RSelenium advise users set the version of Chrome to the most recent version or the version found in their Chrome drivers folder. For example:
# Latest
rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),
         chromever = "latest",
         port = free_port())

# Specific version
rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),
         chromever = "114.002.03.200",
         port = free_port())

This is demonstrated in the most thorough video I found describing RSelenium's installation and set-up (as of 2023), which directs you to use binman::list_versions("chromedriver") to find the Chrome drivers you have installed and then advises you to use one of the returned versions as a value for the chromever argument of rsDriver(). Most resources advise similar approaches.
One of the issues that can arise with this is that the driver versions for Chrome that are installed might not match the version of the Chrome application you currently have installed. For example, binman::list_versions() showed three driver versions all below 115.0 were installed but my current Chrome version (found by entering chrome://version into the Chrome address bar) was >124.0. Choosing one of the versions found via binman can throw an error, such as:

Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114.
Current browser version is 124.0.6362.00.

When my installed version of Chrome does not match the drivers I have installed, what should I do to install or specify the correct versions? This seems particularly likely to happen when I have the most recent version of Chrome installed.

To get the ChromeDriver version that matches the most recent version of Chrome (or the one you have installed) visit https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. As of writing this, the site notes, "If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard." You can visit the accompanying link to download the latest stable release. As long as the major release version (e.g. the 124 in 124.3234) matches your current install, you should be good.
After installation (on Windows), you should extract to the directory where your other version of ChromeDriver are installed. You can find the directory with the following R code:
wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE, check = FALSE)

In my case, this led to a directory within AppData that contained a sub-directory for each driver version installed. After extracting the folder, follow the instructions in the video you linked - deleting the license file and setting chromever to the version of the new driver.
The underlying issue seems to be that the ChromeDriver doesn't necessarily update when Chrome itself is updated and Selenium doesn't automatically download the drivers either when it cannot find the specified version. All you're doing is manually adding the correct driver.

Note: this question is similar to but more specific and clearer version of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518680/how-to-find-a-chrome-driver-for-my-chrome-version
